# AJAX call - success function runs async and messes up order of execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two ajax calls.
In first ajax call, I get all userIds (with user title information).
In second ajax call, I get all items and I try to match userIds with item user ID, so that I can assign correct user title to item.
Afterwards I have exporting to excel file.

What happens is that before it's gone through for loops and compared userIds with item userId and match them, it exports excel file. It should wait for 'for' loops to finish. How to do this correctly?

This is how it looks like, this is global function and firstly I get all data (site users)

```js
this.AllSiteUsers = [];

$.ajax({
  url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers",
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    AllSiteUsers = data.d.results;
    console.log("All SiteUsers GET Successfully");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving items: ", error);
  }
});
```

this function is called on click:

```js
async function exporting() {

  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: siteUrl + '_api/Lists/getbyTitle(\'' + listTitle + '\')/items',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(xData) {
            for (let i = 0; i < xData.value.length; i++) {
              var itemData = xData.value[i];
              if (itemData.UserId) {
                for (let j = 0; j < AllSiteUsers.length; j++) {
                  console.log((AllSiteUsers[j].Id == itemData.UserId));
                  if (AllSiteUsers[j].Id == itemData.UserId) {
                    xData.value[i].User = AllSiteUsers[j].Title;
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }

              const rows = xData.value.map(itemData => ({
                  ID: itemData.ID,
                  User: itemData.User

                });
                //EXPORTING
                const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(rows);
                const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new(); XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Dates"); XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [
                  ['columns']
                ], {
                  origin: "A1"
                });


                XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "DataExport.xlsx", {
                  compression: true
                });
              }
```

Comment: I think you should fix your parentheses/braces first. The current version just gives a syntax error.

Comment: Is `AllSiteUsers` empty when the for j loop runs?

Comment: Is there only one workbook in total, or is there one workbook for each `i`?

Comment: Don't export in the loop. Generate all the data in the loop, then export it at once at the end.

Comment: @James no, data is there

Comment: @qrsngky there is only one workbook in total, I export it after for loop

Comment: @Barmar, I export it only after loops

Comment: It seems that your export is placed within the body of `for (let i = 0; i ...`, though (not outside the loop), because of your levels of nesting. Check your placements of `}` and `)`